# How do you describe the sound of a body being dragged through the snow?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, characters, word-choice, description

How to describe the sound of a body bring dragged through snow

Comment: That's a [white noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise) if there ever was one.

Answer (score 2):

## How is it being dragged?

The other question is, what kind of snow? From Minnesota and Wisconsin, I've dragged plenty of stuff through snow - including bodies (okay, DEER bodies). The most distinctive thing about most snow is how little other noise there seems to be - you can hear the wind, which you otherwise often can't. On a really cold day, with almost no moisture in the air, sound seems amplified and seems to carry further. So every motion is amplified.

The most distinctive noise isn't usually what is being dragged (which, through snow, is surprisingly quiet) but of your feet crunching into the the snow (the noise with snow shoes on is different, but similar enough that the description can be the same). If there is a thin layer of ice atop the snow, there's a steady tinkling like tiny fragile glass items breaking.

Cross-country skiing while dragging anything is difficult, but the least noisy on its own. There's a gentle swoosh of the skis, but the actual dragging sounds like a very muted version of dragging over gravel - a soft grinding sound.

From there, you could be using poles or a sled, and those would be quite different. I assume you mean dragging with a rope, but otherwise it's about the same noises but more in bursts of noise.